# Returning total number of rows from an SQL query (wordpress $wpdb) ignoring the Limit

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Is it possible in Wordpress to return the total number of results from $wpdb->get_results ignoring the limit?

Example:

```
$datas = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_excerpt FROM wp_posts
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON
    wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
    WHERE (
            wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%hello%' OR
            wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%hello%'
          )
          AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
          AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page')

    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 0, 24
", ARRAY_A);
```

Or would I need to run two queries, one with count(*) for the total number of posts and then another as the above query to get the actual post content?

Comment: So you only want to have `count(*)` in your results?

Comment: @revo, I'd like to return 24 posts at a time but I'd like to know what the total count is without the limit as well, so I was wondering if that can be done in one query or would I need to run two queries

Answer (score 2):

You could include `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option in your select query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...
```

Then invoke [`FOUND_ROWS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) immediately:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

However, it's up to you to compare performing time of running a separate query over using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option. Sometimes the former outperforms the latter.

Comment: How would I go about incorporating this functionality into $wpdb->get_results?

Comment: After adding that option to your current select query, you would do `$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()" );`

Comment: I tried this but when I add SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to the first query, it returns nothing

Comment: Did you call `FOUND_ROWS()` afterward?

Comment: Yes, it returns the number '1', which is incorrect and as mentioned, adding SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to the previous query returns nothing

Comment: Adding `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to the select query SHOULD NOT return anything. You have the number of total rows just after invoking `FOUND_ROWS()` function. Please [read manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows). I'm not sure about wordpress `get_results` method. There may be something wrong with it.

Comment: Ok I've read the manual, so I went to PHPMyAdmin and ran the two queries immediately adjacent to each other like so: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM wp_posts LIMIT 0, 12; SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` but still the second query only returns '1' whereas it should return '40,000'